# Creating large extruded polygon which follows Earth's curvature using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: shapefile, polygon, arcgis-pro, curvature

I am trying to create a shapefile of a large ocean volume for manipulating some CMIP6 data. I am currently approaching this by defining a polygon in ArcGIS Pro, and then extruding this is a negative Z direction into the ocean. Unfortunately, my polygon is not following the Earth's curvature, so the lines of my polygon are cutting through the ocean, and as such I cannot extrude the polygon in a sensible way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include CRS and extent.

Comment: I am using WGS 1984 for the XY and Z coordinate systems. My scene properties says 'Use extent of data in all layer'

Comment: You probably need to densify the boundaries to use great circle routes.